# “Program is not a recognized executable” error in Eclipse Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I know that this question has been posted before but I'm still not able to make it work, obviously I'm new to C++  ;)
I have this "hello world!" C++ program in eclipse using CDT, and I'm able to compile it and it works if I run it from a console .... but when I use the run or debug commands inside eclipse ,I'm getting two different errors:

From debug: "Program is not a recognized executable"

From run : "Exec_tty error:Cannot run program "/blah/blah/CProjects/Practice/MAIN.cpp": Unknown reason"

I tried by modifying the parser on the project , but no luck ...I'm actually using GNU Elf parser , and I used gdb from the command line and runs normally so obviously (to me at least ) is something wrong in my eclipse configuration ...but what??

Thanks a lot

D

Comment: "I know that this question has been posted before but I'm still not able to make it work". Why? Were the previous answers unhelpful ?

Comment: You can't run a cpp file, you have to compile it first. Try g++.

Comment: jvivenot :I did try all the solutions in the previous posts about this very same topic, and it did't work...basically it was always the same : change the parser.

Comment: tjameson: the program is compiled, as I said , but is called "Practice" like my project, and MAIN.cpp is the program containing the logic in theproject.. does it make sense to you?

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood the question. The error says you're trying to run source code directly.

Comment: All sorted now..I didn't know you have to set manually the target of the debug/run, I thought that eclipse will be picking up the one in the folder called binaries....thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot *run* the C++ source code.  You have to run the executable.

In the Eclipse environment, a simple "debug" command should do the right thing.  You must have confused it by configuring the source code as the debugger target.

Comment: You're right sir... all working now, I thought that eclipse will automatically know what to debug/run in a project, but apparently you have to specify it ...and I did it wrong!   Thanks a lot!!