# No binaries after building in eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I just installed Eclipse Luna for C++ and try to launch a project. There is no error after I build the project however, when I try to run it, it shows that there is an error.

[image]

I suspect that the problem how it's build or maybe that Eclipse cannot see g++ compiler (I installed Eclipse before g++) or  whatever. It doesn't seem that the problem is related to code.

[image]

I use Elf binary parser. What can be the problem of launching? How can I run my file?

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system you are using?

Looks like mac, then go with MAC OSx GCC.

worth looking at 
 [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500989/program-is-not-a-recognized-executable-error-in-eclipse-ubuntu)